# Trouble accessing variables within an object

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a List that is full of objects from another class than where I am trying to grab the variables.

I thought I could use a foreach loop and go through the list of objects then grab the variables like i normally would but i only am getting the methods from the class I'm trying to pull from

```
 public void fillArray()
    {
        foreach(Assignment1.Post p in Assignment1.allPosts)
        {
            postTitle = p.PostTitle;
            postID = p.PostID;
            postContent = p.PostContent;
            postScore = p.Score;
            date = p.TimeStamp;

            DisplayObjects newObj = new DisplayObjects(postTitle, postID,postContent,postScore,date,timeStamp);

            postObjects.Add(newObj);
        }

        sortList();

    }
```

here is the object declaration and here is where i am trying to access it in another class:

```
 foreach (DisplayObjects d in DisplayObjects.sortedPosts)
        {
             // d.VariablesIWantToAccessButCant
        }
```

Probably something extremely basic but I just am missing the core concept. Thanks for the help as always

Comment: Please put the class definition of Post and DisplayObjects. And what is DisplayObjects.sortedPsts - is it a list of objects, how was it populated?

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to share your problem. What you asking for is unclear. What is your goal and your difficulty? What have you done so far? Please try to better explain your issue, your development environment and the data structures, as well as to share more code (no screenshot), images or sketches of the screen, and user stories or scenario diagrams. To help you improve your requests, please read the *[How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)* and **Questions I avoid asking** at the top right.

Answer (score 0):

All of my variables being placed into the objects were private so I was not able to access them since I had no get or set methods. Very dumb but I figured it out

Comment: You can't access private fields outside the class or in derived class unless you provide getter and setter or use reflexion, so I don't understand your question.